# how to optimize image uploading in iOS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm using iOS in front end to upload the image by using the following encode script,

```
    Ti.Utils.base64encode(get_image);
```

In back end i'm using the following script to decode the image in Rails.

```
    Base64.decode64(encrypted_image)
```

Now, this is working fine in Local ENV. (Time taken to upload 10sec). Now the problem is the same script takes 30seconds in Production ENV.

How to optimize this?

Comment: How big is the image? What kind of service do you use? Is it a REST service where you POST the image? I don't believe the performance killer is encoding/decoding base64. But the question is, why you encode/decode and not just send the image binary?

Comment: The maximum image size is upto 2 MB. Using HTTP CLIENT to post image from device to server. I tried to upload image without encoding but it takes more time to upload compare with sending encoded image.

Comment: Don't know how compression changes this, but Base64 encoding add 1/3 of size to your image, so I believe you will loose time encoding the image. Have a look at the differences in network between ENV and PROD.